# How to get my localhost with a different directory to my index working?

Tags: 12.10, apache2

I can't get my apache configuration to open my `index.html`
I edited my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and added the following at the bottom.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /media//DATA/directory/to/my/index-file/
ServerName host-test.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I restarted my system. But, when I open `localhost` I get the:

> It works!
>
> This is the default web page for this server.
>
> The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

How to get `localhost`, with a different directory to my index, working in Ubuntu 12.10(amd64)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the data via the name localhost, change the `ServerName` directive from `host-test.com` to `localhost`.

You can also set wildcards for the server name, to deliver the files under several names.

You should consider reading the Apache Documentation section regarding Virtual Hosts.

More important: take a look at the directory `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` and `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. This is where your site configurations should go for easy maintenance, not in the main apache2.conf file. Your VHost definition might even interfere with the `default` host definition. You can run `sudo a2dissite default` to disable the demo site.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this when i get home. BTW my index is located in an external partition(NTFS) should that be a problem?

Comment: as long as the web server (user www-data) has read permissions this will not be a problem. In any case you will notice if this should become the stopper.

Comment: It worked changing the `host-test.com` to `localhost` thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to set up additional root addresses apart from "localhost".
This needs a little more work.

This tutorial is a little old but should work on 12.10
http://tuxtweaks.com/2009/07/how-to-configure-apache-linux/